# Error using dynamic 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays

so recently I have been working on a truth table generator which generates an equation for a logic statement. So, I decided to use a 2D array to make things seem more clean and neat. However, as I run this code(Don't worry, int main and other functions exist too, I am posting only this part since it is the one that causes an error):

```
int calculate(size_t length) {

    int dimensionX = length + 2;
    int dimensionY = 5;
    calcArray = new string *[dimensionX];
    for (int i = 0; i < dimensionX; i++) {
        calcArray[i] = new string[dimensionY];
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < dimensionX; i++) {
        delete[] calcArray[i];
        delete[] calcArray;
    }

    return 0;
}

int count(string phrase, string calcArray[][]) {
    string statement(phrase);
    size_t ve = count(statement.begin(), statement.end(), 'A');
    size_t yada = count(statement.begin(), statement.end(), 'V');
    size_t ozel_yada = count(statement.begin(), statement.end(), 'XV');
    size_t ok = count(statement.begin(), statement.end(), '->');
    size_t cift_ok = count(statement.begin(), statement.end(), '<->');
    size_t complete = ve + yada + ozel_yada + ok + cift_ok;
    size_t column_number = complete;
    return complete;

    for (int i = 3; i < complete; i++) {
    int andNum = phrase.find('A');
    if (count (phrase.substr(andNum-3,6).begin(), phrase.substr(andNum - 3, 6).end(),'(') == 0){
        string calcArray[0][i] = phrase.substr(andNum - 1, 4);
    }
}
```

}

I get errors saying that:

> > An array may not have elements of this type(   int count(string phrase, string calcArray[][])
> >
> > cannot allocate an array of constant size 0 (string calcArray[0][i] = phrase.substr(andNum - 1, 4);)
> >
> > An expression did not evaluate a constant (string calcArray[0][i] = phrase.substr(andNum - 1, 4);)

I would appreciate any help or explanation. Thanks

Comment: Where you have `string calcArray[0][i] = ...` (at the bottom of your code) are you sure you want the declaration instead of just `calcArray[0][i] = ...`?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I don't understand why you are redeclaring calcArray in your last line of posted code, although I guess it's kind of a moot point.

Comment: So, since this is a dinamic array, at start I used string **calcArray = 0; so will it work if I just say string **calcArray at the beggining of the count function

Comment: No, sorry for the confusion. I am pointing out what I think is a second error in your posted code. For your actual question, I recommend looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767166/passing-a-2d-array-to-a-c-function

Answer (score 1):

```
string calcArray[][]
```

is not a valid declaration for a function parameter. When you use a multi-dimensional array, all dimensions except the first one must be specified. E.g.

```
string calcArray[][10]


string anotherArray[][10][2]
```

If the arrays are dynamic, you can use `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>`.

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>& calcArray
```